# i'm taking image url from database. But it is not working in img tag in php

Tags: php, html

The name of the column is : link. variable-type:varchar.

```
<img src="<?php echo$link;?>" style="width:300px; height:400px;" />
</html>
```

Comment: Echo out the image link somewhere to check if it's okay.

Comment: Come on! You can do better than that: 1) what is your objective? 2) What is/are the languages you're writing it? 3) Is that all the code available? 4) What is going wrong? 5) Do you have any log of the error?

Comment: What is the output of: `var_dump($link)` ?

Comment: @aldux Some of those answer themselves already. I agree on the last two points though. But the first 3 are quite obvious.

Answer (score 0):

Your echo command could be missing an ";"

```
$link=$row['link'];
<img src="<?php echo $link; ?>" style="width:300px; height:400px;" />
```

Should work better.

Comment: this is also not working;  $link1="../ALL/background.jpg"<img src="<?phpecho$link1;?>" style="width:300px; height:400px;" />

Comment: based on your Informations try the URL without php… if it works come again ;)

Comment: you could try and preform your database query in the following code section <img src="<?php /*here*/echo $link1; ?>"